# jQuery UI layout hard-coding/methods

Tags: jquery

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var outerLayout;

        var layoutSettings_Outer = {
.
.
.
        };

        outerLayout = $("#layout").layout(layoutSettings_Outer);
.
.
.
    });
```

And in the body I'm using:

```
<div id="layout">
     <div class="ui-layout-center">
          <div>
              <a href="#" onClick="outerLayout.open('east'); return false;">Close left side</a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-layout-east">
           Right Panel
      </div>
      <div class="ui-layout-west">
          Left Panel
      </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is the link that is supposed to *close the 'east' - left layout (in )*. Unfortunately it doesn't. I have no idea what to do...

> The Firefox's console says: "ReferenceError: outerLayout is not defined".
>   **BTW - The whole layout works perfectly so JavaScript can see those divs.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this... But I'm not sure why it's like that!
I've just removed the `var outerLayout;` before the `$(document).ready(function(){` code! Is this all about global/local attribute of outerLayout?